# google.com not displaying search suggestions and sing in button doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome

I will get search suggestions if queries are typed into the Chrome address bar but not when they're typed into the google.com main page search bar.

I'm getting an exception on input or on the 'Sing in' button click:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null
at s_dh.s_.get (rs=ACT90oGAIwn6uIcvgXJ2ElAML1jBlGXwSQ:368)
at s_WAb (rs=ACT90oGAIwn6uIcvgXJ2ElAML1jBlGXwSQ:3879)
at s_1Ab.ka (rs=ACT90oGAIwn6uIcvgXJ2ElAML1jBlGXwSQ:3883)
at s__s.xq (rs=ACT90oGAIwn6uIcvgXJ2ElAML1jBlGXwSQ:3766)
at s_6Bb (rs=ACT90oGAIwn6uIcvgXJ2ElAML1jBlGXwSQ:3892)
at s_5Bb (rs=ACT90oGAIwn6uIcvgXJ2ElAML1jBlGXwSQ:3892)
at rs=ACT90oGAIwn6uIcvgXJ2ElAML1jBlGXwSQ:3892
at s_Vs.Ui (rs=ACT90oGAIwn6uIcvgXJ2ElAML1jBlGXwSQ:3711)
at s_Ys.initialize (rs=ACT90oGAIwn6uIcvgXJ2ElAML1jBlGXwSQ:3733)
at new s_lt (rs=ACT90oGAIwn6uIcvgXJ2ElAML1jBlGXwSQ:4224)
```

Tried to reinstall Chrome and turn off all extensions - no results

**Enviroment:**

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- Chrome 89.0.4389.90

Comment: Sorry I do not see what this has to do with Ubuntu it is a Chrome problem

Comment: @David what is the correct place to post it? google support didn't give me any response

Comment: All you can do is search for other support sites for that app.